# Neo4j webadmin does not start

Tags: neo4j

I have just downloaded neo4j database (community edition 1.8.M07) and started neo4j.bat. After that when I go to `http://localhost:7474/webadmin/`, I can't execute any query in "Explore and Edit - Data browser" tab. It always displays following text in the query textbox.

```
START root=node(0) // Start with the reference node
RETURN root        // and return it.

// Hit CTRL+ENTER to execute
```

When I type some text in the query textbox and hit search, it displays following error:
"Unknown error
An unknown error occurred, was unable to retrieve a result for you.
"
Edit: the same error occurs when I try to add a new Node(using the +Node button).
Do I need to do anything extra for get it running?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you typing in the query text box when it gives you that error?

Comment: any text(like my name). Also I get the same error when I tried to add a new node using the +Node button. I have updated the question as well  to mention this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. In the query box I need to write the query and simply writing any text (such as myName) is not correct way. But the "Unknown error" was misleading. somehow the error on clicking the Create Node button is also disappeared. I hope neo4j team work on it to give some proper error when the query is not in correct format.

Comment: Yeah, it's confusing for people using the interface the first time. I actually prefer the console window so I can hit up/down to go back to the old queries and edit them.

Comment: Would be great if you wanna make a screencast on how to use things? Would be highly appreciated by first-timers I think. Also, if you find strange stuff, please raise issues at https://github.com/neo4j/community/issues